# When are EcuMDriverInitListBswM lists executed?

Tags: autosar

I want to know when EcuMDriverInitListBswM lists are executed? Are they executed during BswM init, or there will be a BswMGenericRequest which is responsible for a mode which will be arbitrated and its true action list contain BswMEcuMDriverInitListBswM action?